# Traverse my data structure, and enter random values to it

Tags: python, c++, c, linux, data-structures

I am having a very big data structure.
Only 1 structure. 
Now, this structure has many sub-structures under it and so on.
I have to put random values to each variable of this structure.
I would have done it manually, but there are more than 10000 variables under it.
It's a long and deep structure, that have structure under structure.

for eg -> This is just an example, actual structure is very big

```
struct qwerty{
    unsigned short  catch;
    unsigned short  port;
    MediaAuthType_e     mediaAuth;
    typeShortNatmr    NAT;
    typeDynEpDom      domain;
    typeRDomList      domainlist;
    typeDom domainSize;
};
```

Now each of these data types has substructure under it 
eg for MediaAuthType_e data type above we have a structre as

```
struct MediaAuthType_e
{
    int nunkhdr;
    msg_body_list* unknown_msg_body;
    int unknown_msg_body_count;
    SipLssHandle Handle;
    InfoEntry *dfo;
    char* ua_uri;
    char* accept;
    void* s_contact;
    char* branch;
    char* chargeNum;
    int 100Supported;
    int 100Required;
 };
```

and so on .

Can someone please help?
I just have to store random values to each of my variables?
Can I automate this process?

EDIT:

Why I am doing this is, 
I have to encode the data to xdr format and decode it to get the same value

Comment: Do you care whether e.g. `char *branch` is a valid pointer?

Comment: Is it feasible to define default constructors for all the structs that fill the members with random values?

Comment: yes @pbn,  it must be a valid pointer.

Comment: Well then they are not `random values`

Comment: Why is it tagged C++, C AND python?

Comment: @MayankKataruka: A valid pointer to a random string? Like: generate a random string, and then `str(n)cpy` it to the struct so you have a valid pointer? Why? I can't even...

Comment: @pbn 
char *branch = "some_random_value";
Now branch will contain a pointer to this string.

Comment: @YSC , I was looking for a solution, even a script should be fine

Comment: Some language environments have reflection, which lets you write a program that can dynamically determine the names and types of variables in nested structures, and set the values. If you want to do something similar for C, you need to parse the structure definitions and generate code.

Answer (score 3):

Following pseudo code will assign random values. However, the pointers will not be valid pointers! It just fills the whole memory area with sequential values.

```
unsigned long int i;        // in case your structure is too Big!
struct MediaAuthType_e *my_MediaAuthType_e;
my_MediaAuthType_e = malloc(sizeof(struct MediaAuthType_e));
char *tmp = (char *)my_MediaAuthType_e;

for(i = 0; i < sizeof(struct MediaAuthType_e); i++)
{
    *tmp = (i%255);         // Assign some values at each byte, use your logic to assign random values.
    tmp++;
}
```

Comment: This is the only "simple" way to do this... but I wouldn't recommend it!